# Cannot follow expansion with summation notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, index-notation

In [this](https://igppweb.ucsd.edu/~guy/sio227a/ch3.pdf) document I cannot follow the expansion made by the author at equation 3.14. I reproduce it here for reference

$$\partial_j[\lambda \delta_{ij}\partial_k u_k+\mu(\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i)]$$

$$=\partial_i \lambda \partial_k u_k+\lambda \partial_i \partial_k u_k+\partial_j \mu (\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i)+\mu \partial_j \partial_iu_j+\mu \partial_j \partial_j u_i$$

Where $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. In the second expression, I can see there is a contraction going on namely for the first term $\partial_j\lambda\delta_{ij}\partial_ku_k = \partial_i\lambda\partial_ku_k$. I can also see that the second term from the first expression reoccurs as the third term in the second expression. However I have no clue where the other terms are coming from.

What are the intermediate steps necessary to arrive at the second expression? Could someone please provide a full expansion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let us first split the left side in two terms:
$$
\partial_j[\lambda \delta_{ij}\partial_k u_k+\mu(\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i)]
= \partial_j[\lambda \delta_{ij}\partial_k u_k] + \partial_j[\mu(\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i)]
$$

For the first term we apply the product rule (noticing $\delta_{ij}$ is constant) and contract over $j$:
$$
\partial_j[\lambda \delta_{ij}\partial_k u_k]
= (\partial_j\lambda)\delta_{ij}\partial_ku_k + \lambda\delta_{ij}(\partial_j\partial_ku_k)
= (\partial_i\lambda)\partial_ku_k + \lambda(\partial_i\partial_ku_k)
$$

For the second term we do the same:
$$
\partial_j[\mu(\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i)]
= (\partial_j\mu)(\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i) + \mu \partial_j(\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i) \\
= (\partial_j\mu)(\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i) + \mu (\partial_j\partial_i u_j+\partial_j\partial_j u_i)
$$

Adding the two results we reach the right hand side of you equation.

Comment: but $\lambda$ is a constant.... it is not a function of $x_j$

Comment: Don't they depend on the medium i.e. the type of rock in the case of seismology?

Comment: They could but I think in this case a uniform medium with linear elastic properties is implied...